# how to access multiple relationship on cakephp

Tags: cakephp, relationship

I am doing a small project using CakePHP and have multiple tables. I have table `questions` which has 2 foreign keys `item_id` and `user_id` (ID of user who asked the question not ID of user who uploaded item) and some other not important fields.

Now, from the `questions` table, I want to access table `items`, which has a foreign key of `user_id` (user who uploaded the item). Then, using the `user_id` from the table `items`, I want to access the table `users` so that I get the ID of the user who uploaded the item.

I tried multiple things but did not manage to do. The last code I tried was this:

```php
$questionToDelete->items->users['user_id']
```

Comment: `debug($questionToDelete)`, inspect the structure and go from there.

Comment: Can you show us more code and from where you are accessing the table.  From within the controller, you will want to use the 'contain' option when getting the table, this will allow you to access the tab.  An example from a project I've done is as follows $policy = $this->Policies->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Users', 'PolicyComponents'],
        ]); .    This allows me to get all the related Users and PolicyComponents.